# Showing preview of Google Groups post links?

Tags: feature-request, chat, markdown-preview

I wonder whether it would be feasible for the chat to show previews of google group post links (for links to usenet). Example:

http://groups.google.com/group/comp.std.c/browse_frm/thread/7a9c50ede3afec49

Could maybe show the name of the poster, the title and the name of the group.

Comment: Here's a similar question I posted a while ago that was not all that well received, at least for the main sites http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7791/popup-preview-of-a-so-sf-su-mso-link-on-mouse-hover-ala-fogbugz